# Sqlite : Comparing timestamp value stored in a column to current Date

Tags: java, android, sqlite, timestamp

I store information in a sqlite database table as follows: 
ActionDate column is of type : `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
    private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

I want to write an SQL query that returns all rows in my table having ActionDate value as today's date from sqlite DB. However as ActionDate  is of type timestamp what is the most appropriate way to convert it to todays date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want current date then use the following query :

```
 SELECT date('now');
```

To get all columns in your table having ActionDate equal to todays date use the below query  :

```
select * from table where strftime('%Y-%m-%d ', datetime(ActionDate, 'unixepoch'))  = date('now)' ;
```

more info on SQLite Date & Time queries can be found [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: i want to retrieve or select today time Stamp form column ActionDate

Comment: what is column ActionDate..is it a column in your DB Table ?
And what does it store ?

Comment: YES it store DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP see my first post

Comment: but i'm just to select it if the current day == ActionDate , But note that ActionDay can't comparable to just date !

Comment: so do you want to get all columns from your table that have ActionDate = Todays date ?

Comment: yes let's make select * from table where ActionDate == TODAY DATE or ActionDate has TODAY DATE

Comment: In that case, your problem is getting collection of action dates / current dates / today dates instead of single. Am I right?

Comment: not working , i has this string in actiondate : 2014-02-25 02:21:14 but when do your statement not return anything

Comment: try executing the following query and tell me what it returns you :  select strftime('%Y-%m-%d ', datetime(ActionDate, 'unixepoch'))  from table;